# RSpec Selenium Linter

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubocop

Are there linters available for selenium / capybara tests written in RSpec? For example, if your organization has a standard around how to access DOM elements is there something like Rubocop for those tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a RuboCop plugin [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/nevir/rubocop-rspec). It only has a few rules, and none are Capybara-specific, but it might give some ideas on how to write your own checks.